# Is the exponentiation on a modulo field conmutative/distributive?

Tags: optimization, finite-fields, programming

I'm trying to wrap my head around exponentiation on a modulo field (specifically the modulo field defined by the Secp256k1 Weirstrass curve).

I'm currently implementing a bignum library on a lesser known language where no other implementation exists (GDScript, looks like python but isn't remotely as capable for big numbers as it).

I basically need to calculate exponentiation like this:

$$Y = X^P \mod F$$

Where F is the field modulo.

And need to do several optimizations (i.e. can't calculate P times X by X, as P is a bignum itself and could take hours for just 1 operation) that are based around conmutative and distributive properties of multiplication to reduce algorithm complexity and make it run on a fast enough timeframe.

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is probably what you need. The number of operations is polynomial in the number of bits you need to represent $P$. You can probably find libraries for the routines in your language of choice.

Comment: But, it feels like your terminology is a bit off. It is not quite clear what you mean by commutative/distributive here, but the rules
$$x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}$$ and $$(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$$
are valid whenever $x$ is an element of a ring, and $a,b$ are integers (non-negative, unless $x$ is invertible when negative is also ok).

Comment: It is possible to implement Elliptic curve crypto primitives on a chip with rather limited resources. You may want to ask at Crypto.SE for sources. Though I don't know whether they think such a request is on-topic.

Comment: In fact, on the language i'm using there isn't anything like this.... most people just resort to natively compiled libraries with external dependencies (and, although that's out of the scope here, i don't want to include managing the external libs for the 10+ target OS/devices combos).

Comment: Your second comment sound more like what i'm looking for, if that's a property of a ring then a prime field should have that property too. Exponentiating by squaring is indeed what i'm implementing, using Barret's reduction. But as that is for a GF(n) and i don't know if Prime fields hold the same properties as Galois Fields, that's what raised my doubts.

Comment: If the selection of elliptic curves includes those defined over a characteristic two field $GF(2^m)$, $m$ relatively large, then you probably want to use a normal basis. Squaring is turned into cyclic shift. This does not work for prime fields.

Comment: Thinking about your last comment: Although the calculations are done in Zp (with p=some known value, which is a subset of GF(256)), these calcs are done on a run of the mill GF(256) with a formula that keeps the results coherent with the Zp field, so maybe i'm just complicating myself and just need to use usual modular arithmetics. Will try and report back.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is NOT a subset of $GF(256)$ in any natural way unless $p=2$, so you lost me in your final comment.

Comment: Ok, I looked up [Secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1). That curve is defined over $\Bbb{Z}_p$, $p$ a prime number approximately $2^{256}$. You do realize that $GF(256)$ has $256$ elements.That is, its elements can be written using $8$ bits instead of $256$. Anyway, $GF(256)$ has nothing whatsoever to do with that curve.

Comment: Over a finite field,  the "freshman's dream" holds when $(a+b)^{p^k} \pmod p = a^{p^k} + b^{p^k} \pmod p$